# Custom Keyword highlighting within comments for VIM

Tags: c++, vim, comments, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to add custom keywords that should be highlighted in vim.
These keywords are for marking comments, not the code.
This is what I have in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd Syntax * syntax keyword Important containedin=.*Comment contained IMPORTANT
```

This works, but only partly, as the keyword (IMPORTANT) is only highlighted when using 'C-Style' comments: ( /* ... */ ), not the shorter( // ... ) notation.
I've played around with the 'containedin=' flag to no success..

This needs to work for C/C++ but obviously would be nice to have in general!

Comment: On a related note, I also have defined new keywords for custom types like so: `syn keyword cType real32 real64`. I have these defined in `$HOME/vimfiles/after/syntax/c.vim` and that works. If I put the same commands into my .vimrc it doesn't. I would like to just have all custom keywords/syntax stuff in there though. Possible, what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

When I trigger that on a `// comment` line in a C++ file, it lists the syntax group as `cCommentL`. So, to fix this, you need to extend the regular expression, either strictly to `containedin=.*CommentL\?`, or more encompassing to `containedin=.*Comment.*`